# Java EE exceptions for validation and APMs

Tags: java, exceptions, error-handling, monitoring

In my current work, we have some Java EE applications and we use exceptions and exception mappers to deal with user errors, i.e. that can't be dealt with in the frontend.

We usually reply with a 400, and make the frontend show a "pretty" message for the user.

Problem is: those exceptions count as errors in our APM (NewRelic, now switching to DripStat which have the same problem).

Is this a common thing, to throw exceptions for invalid user input? Is there any standard for this kind of thing? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http codes has nothing to be with business (validation) errors. Some ppl use HTTP error codes to encode their catatalog of errors. But I don't think it's a good practice.

Http errors are related to the protocol (http). So any business exception  thrown by your code, should be (in my oponion) handled and returned as a missage. And of course into a 200 Http respone.

Runtime Exceptions (unexpected errors) can be returned as Http 500 unless you want to control every possible runtime exception, handle it and transform it into a controlled error message (in such case, response will be Http 200).

An error 500 means *unrecovery error*. The **business** can not continue, there's no alternative flow, so *end of the request* and *your request has not been processed*.

I prefer to define a complex respone message: header, body, attributes, ... And also a inner *code* that it doesn't follow Http response codes. If *code* is informed , server is notifying something beside the result of the executed process.

The only codes I would reuse from HTTP catalog, would be:

200: request processed and respone sent. If the business process finished successfuly or not doesn't matter. We got the request and we were able to perform validations, processes, etc. For more info check out response messge.

500: Any unexpected error. Something wrong happened. It's not related to the business, it might be something eventual. However the business process finished premsturaly. Client doesn't need to know what happened. We may be giving too much info about our system. So let error go as 500. Let client to deal with.

403: Forbbiden access (and this one, not always. Only if there's no special business at client side).

Otherwise you are coupling *protocol* *responses* with *business* *responses*. Then, client side, may fall into error of unexpected redirections, unexpected end of flows executions, ...

Edit: So far, there's standard to follow. Any stratgey is right if it fit in your requirements

Comment: Don't forget Authentication Required and 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 2):

From the [HTTP spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

```
10.4.1 400 Bad Request

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.
```

which doesn't sound quite appropriate for the above scenario. Without know more of what you're doing and your requirements, I would normally bounce invalid user input back via a normal page + 200 status code. If, however, I was supporting a REST-style (or other scriptable) HTTP interface, I would make more use of the wide range of error codes.

(surely you can configure NewRelic to understand your particular application, if you need?)